HTML <header b-tg5po7urw9> What is b-tg... produced by using Razor generate MVC
I built a simple sample app RazorPagesMovie and examined the source page for Index part of the app and many of the elements are followed by b-tg5po7urw9. I can find no explanation of what that file/reference might be or be used for?
Example:
<body>
    <header b-tg5po7urw9>
        <nav b-tg5po7urw9 class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div b-tg5po7urw9 class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Movies">RpMovie</a>
                <button b-tg5po7urw9 class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span b-tg5po7urw9 class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

I have been through various tutorials, but have seen no reference to <tag b-tg... etc

This is used when scoping CSS styles and is actually pretty common among frontend JS frameworks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-9.0#css-isolation-bundling

Within the bundled file, each component is associated with a scope identifier. For each styled component, an HTML attribute is appended with the format b-{STRING}, where the {STRING} placeholder is a ten-character string generated by the framework. The identifier is unique for each app. In the rendered Counter component, Blazor appends a scope identifier to the h1 element:

<h1 b-3xxtam6d07>


The {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css file uses the scope identifier to group a style declaration with its component. The following example provides the style for the preceding  element:

/* /Components/Pages/Counter.razor.rz.scp.css */
h1[b-3xxtam6d07] {
    color: brown;
}

